# Why my .NET MVC application session never expire?

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-4

NET Framework 4.8

MVC 5.2.3.0

.NET Identity 2.0

I set this in Web.Config:

```
<sessionState timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

this supposedly will log user out after 1 minute inactivity. But it doesn't at all.

I can see that after more than 1 minute inactivity, if I click some menu of the appication, it will come to here, which means that a new session is created. But the problem is that, the user is not logged out.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
}
```

What are the possible reasons that the user is never logged out after session expiration? Sorry I have no code to provide since I am not sure which part to provide.